# The label outlet is invalid

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform, xcode6

I want to declare the 4 labels which in my table prototype cells so that I can retrieve all the data from Parse into the label. As you see in the picture, there're 4 labels, I want each of them have their own outlet, but it showing me the invalid outlet error.
[image: This is the prototype cells and contain 4 labels in it.]

I'm using the Parse to do it, so that the superclass of the prototype cell will be the PFTableViewCell.

```
class TimetableViewController: PFQueryTableViewController, UITextFieldDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var lblTime: UILabel!
```

The error that I got will be like this...

> The lblTime outlet from the TimetableViewController to the UILabel is
>   invalid. Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content.

Therefore, what should I do to avoid this problem exist?

Comment: There is 2 solutions...,1st use custom class for cell and another one is to use tag property

Comment: @Bhavin Yup, I did use the custom class for it, but I've created a new file for the UITableViewCell, I still can't access the label even the label outlet is there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a custom subclass of `UITableViewCell` and declare your `IBOutlets` there. Then you use that subclass instead of the generic `UITableViewCell` throughout your main view controller.

To reiterate: elements inside a tableview cell belong to the cell, not to the view controller that contains everything.

Edit:
In your view controller, you would conform to UITableView's delegate & datasource protocols (and implement any methods that are relevant to what you're trying to accomplish). You would handle populating (initial) cell data in the follow data source method:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TimetableViewCell
    // TODO: setup cell data here
    return cell
}
```

Comment: So let say I got one TimeTableViewController which subclass from `PFQueryTableViewController`, then I open another table cell file, which is TimetableViewCell sub from `UITableViewCell`, then the prototype cell bind to `TimetableViewCell` and the whole storyboard bind to `TimeTableViewController` right?

Comment: Correct. In your view controller, you would declare yourself the tableview's data source & delegate (most likely) and handle cell configuration in those methods.

Answer (score 1):

Cells are generated on the fly. There is no real connection between the controller and the cell so you cannot connect something in the cell to a controller. Specifically, usually you have multiple cells of the same type ("repeated content") and you can't have all of the labels connected to one outlet in the parent controller.

Typically, what you want to do is declare a class for the cell, e.g.

```
class MyCell : UITableCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var lblTime: UILabel!

}
```

and add the outlet to it.

Comment: So I need to have two file which are View Controller and View Cell for the storyboard and prototype cells?

Comment: you dont need two files but you need two classes

Comment: how to say like two classes? open two classes in a file?

Comment: I am talking about code. You need two classes in code. The storyboard won't change.

Comment: Ya, I've added two classes, now I can add the outlet of the label, but in the function, but I can't access the label in the tableView function still...I've two classes in one view controller now...

Answer (score 0):

[image]
For those that errors still exist after you delete the IBOutlet code from your view controller you still need to right click it and delete the old connection. After deleting it the error message will go away.

This cleared all my errors. Hope will help others as well.